# How apple know you have the Apple Store app installed from the website?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

When you visit the `apple.com` and they will have a prompt said that you have the "Apple Store app" installed and suggest you to open, how it is possible just from the broswer?

**Update:**

So, assume my app with bundle id `com.example.myapp` and registered the url scheme `myapp://`., what would be the **JavaScript** I can used in my site to check if the app is installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple has developed a meta tag that you can include in your website that can check if an app is installed by its app ID and if it is already installed open it. It is important to remember that on their platform Apple can do anything they want, and this is a great example. Mobile Safari has been programmed to take advantage of the presence of this tag to display the download/open banner.

Below is the meta tag where all you have to do is pass the app id, but **IF** you have a URL scheme you can use it here as well to pass arbitrary arguments to your application.

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=MYAPPID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURLScheme://">
```

Comment: So you mean it is not possible to do in our own website to check our own app? How about if we are using the `UIWebView` instead of `Mobile Safari`?

Comment: @Yoga You can use this in your own website for your app. All you have to do is replace "MYAPPID" with the app id of your app that you can find in iTunes Connect. This should work in web view's as well.

Answer (score 0):

They use custom url scheme, something like `macappstore://linktoapporwhatever`. The `macappstore` is register as a protocol at the os level, the same way `http` is, and is associated with `App Store.app`

Comment: Thanks, so it is not possible with our own apps/sites?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not public functionality. The URL scheme registered by your app does not show up in the list of schemes in JavaScript.

You should file an enhancement request on Apple's Bug Reporter.